# How to develop application for both 320x480 and 480x854?

Tags: java, android

i to implement my same application for both 320x480 and 480x854 resolutions. For this purpose i copied my images in hdpi and mdpi drawable folders but still it is not working with480x854 resolution. What i must do other than this to solve my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't just copy your images in both folders.  The hdpi folder should have larger (higher dpi) images than the mdpi folder.

For instance, menu icons should be 72x72 pixels in the hdpi folder, and only 48x48px in the mdpi folder.  If you only have 1 image in the mdpi folder, and the user has a high res device, then it will load that 1 image but upscale it.  However, that doesn't look the best.

It's a good practice to have multiple versions of each image for high, medium, and low res devices.

Answer (score 1):

What is your concrete problem? Are the hdpi graphics not in use?
Not only the screen size influences, which graphic resources are used - the dpi of the screen too.

Maybe the following link will help: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html